# How to enqueue a jobworkitem with a jobscheduler

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, mobile

Almost no examples on the internet for JobWorkItem in Android.

Trying to add work to a job (using JobScheduler framework) in Android. But my intent of JobWorkItem is never fired. Trying to use [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler.html#enqueue(android.app.job.JobInfo,%20android.app.job.JobWorkItem)) method to be particular. I noticed the breakpoint in my service (JsonDownloadIntentService) is never hit.

```
MainActivity.java

private void startJobService() {
        JobScheduler jobScheduler = (JobScheduler) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
        jobScheduler.schedule(getJobInfo());
    }

    private JobInfo getJobInfo() {
        if(jobInfo == null) {
           jobInfo =  (new JobInfo.Builder(10, new ComponentName(getApplicationContext().getPackageName(), EmptyJobService.class.getName()))).setMinimumLatency(0).setOverrideDeadline(5000).build();
        }
        return jobInfo;
    }

    private void enqueueWorkItem() {
        Intent startJsonDownloadService = new Intent(this, JsonDownloadIntentService.class);
        ((JobScheduler)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE)).enqueue(getJobInfo(), new JobWorkItem(startJsonDownloadService));
    }
```

EmptyJobService.java

```
        public class EmptyJobService extends JobService {
        @Override
        public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters params) {
            Log.d(Constants.JOB_SERVICE, "Job Service started");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters params) {
            Log.d(Constants.JOB_SERVICE, "Job service stopped");
            return false;
        }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.viewer.myphotoviewer">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
   <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">


        <activity android:name=".PhotoGalleryActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service android:name=".ImageDownloadIntentService" />
        <service android:name=".JsonDownloadIntentService" />
        <service android:name=".EmptyJobService"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE"
            android:exported="true"
            />

        <activity android:name=".ImageViewActivity"></activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

is it declared in the manifest, along with the permission?

```
<service
android:name=".MyJobService"
android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. 
Yes, the job service is fired, its the jobworkitem intent that is not executed. I could know it from logs:
com.viewer.myphotoviewer D/job_service: Job Service started

Answer (score 0):

When you return false from onStartJob() it means you are saying to the system that, once this method returns my job is done. So android framework fires onJobFinished() on your behalf. 
But when you return true, it means your job needs to run beyond this callback and you get the responsibility to call onJobFinished when the work is done.

You need to use dequeue() of JobParameters received and get your workitem which was enqueued. Once your job is done, call completeWork(WorkItem).
    After all the work is processed, call dequeue at last so the system ends your job service by calling jobFinished() on your behalf.

**Please read this article which I have written explaining JobWorkItem API along with a working example for JobWorkItem.**

https://medium.com/@kiitvishal89/jobworkitem-jobschedulers-way-of-splitting-your-job-d6d5385390b